# SSRS Subscription failed

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, exchange-server, ssrs-2012, ssrs-subscription

I am trying to find out why am I getting the following Error when I sent out subscription:

> Failure sending mail: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.1.1 User unknown.

I checked all the Email addresses in the Groups of recipients, they all are valid. However there is one person is just out of office for couple days. Can anyone help me to figure this issue out?

Comment: I would assume you have communicated with your exchange/ad admin about this?  if the user has a full mailbox, that would give a similar response.

Comment: Thank you GoldBishop. Exchange Admin found the issue in one of the mailboxes and he fixed it!

Comment: Give the man an upvote for fixing your problem, Shan!

Comment: @Lucky thanx ;)

Comment: @Lucky I don't even know how to give an upvote, is it because I don't have enough reputation, Lucky